# I am not able to see the tabs in spring config editor in Spring STS plugin

Tags: spring, ide, spring-batch

I am trying to see the graphical user interface to look my spring batch jobs.

I can't see spring batch graphs in Editor.

In dependency graph, the tabs are not shown at the bottom.

Someone please help me.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It isn't very clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring config files are not added. They were not automatically detected.

The way add that.

Project properites -> Spring -> Bean Support -> Config files.

Answer (score 0):

I miss information in your question, but i can think of 3 possibilities:

.) You didnt open your xml with the spring config editor. Close the file in your IDE, right click -> open with -> other -> spring config editor.

.) You didnt add spring project nature to your project. Right click on your project -> Spring tools -> add spring project nature.

.) You miss the batch-context in your xml. Open the file with the spring config editor, click namespaces, add batch, save it and you should see the batch and batch-graph tab at the bottom.